# Unable to connect to SQL Server running in container inside Ubuntu VM on Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
    coreapi:
        build:
            context: ./theapi
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
    sqlserver:
        build:
            context: ./sqlserver
        ports:
            - "1433:1433"    
        environment: 
            - ACCEPT_EULA="Y"
            - SA_PASSWORD="Pwd12345!"
    angular:
        build:
            context: ./frontend
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "4300:4200"
```

[image]

I read similar post on stackoverflow and add opened inbound port on my VM.

But to no avail:

[image]

**Edit:**
[image]

Comment: I assume the password above isn't what's in your real compose file. Just as an experiment try using a password of uppercase letters, lowercase letters and digits only eight characters or longer to meet SQL Server's sa password complexity requirement. Some punctuation characters could be messing with YML or shell escapes at run time.

Comment: Can you share the context of your sqlserver? And I recommend you can test if you can connect to the sqlserver inside the VM and the container.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I checked the password that I set in yml file with nano.. Its the same. Pwd12345!

Comment: @CharlesXu I havent been able to connect to it from within container.. i get sqlcmd not found

Comment: It's just a tool, you can install it to take a test.

Comment: @CharlesXu I already have. I installed it on Ubuntu VM follwing these steps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-ver15#ubuntu

Comment: So what is the result for the test?

Comment: Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'sa'..

Comment: @CharlesXu and this is what I had executed `sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P Pwd1235!
`

Comment: So it's the problem with your container in the VM. Just check if the container runs well and if yes, go inside the container to check the sqlserver if it's fine.

Comment: What about the result of the rest now?

Comment: @CharlesXu container is running fine, see my edit. How do I check it inside container? I did `sudo docker exec -it 51f250a8d0f6 bash
` and then ran the same `sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P Pwd12345!` and got sqlcmd not found.. I guess I need that tool inside container as well. I am not sure how.

Comment: To ssh into the container is also useful. But you need to find the sqlcmd command first and it's in the path /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd. Or you can run the command `docker exec -it <container_id|container_name> /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P <your_password>` directly.

Comment: @CharlesXu I havent tried to connect it using exec -it yet but i checked logs  and it seems i am getting ` Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: 182.140.233.109]
`

Comment: how is that possible?

Comment: `sudo docker exec -it be112a0efcd6 /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P Pwd12345
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'sa'..
` I even changed the password in Docker-compose fie to Pwd12345 (removed special char)

Comment: @CharlesXu there is definately something wrong with the way I am creating containers. Because I tried `docker run --name sqlserver --hostname sqlserver -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=1StrongPwd!!" -p 1433:1433 -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest 
` and I was able to login via sqlcmd on vm

Comment: I am able to connect to sql server even with public ip if i just build a single sql container with just Dockerfile. It is just the docker-compose that is giving me trouble

Answer (score 0):

NSG - Inbound port rule -> Allow any "source port" to connect to your Sql server running in Docker by changing the value from 1433 to *.

It will resolve your issue. I replicated your steps and reproduced your issue. This fix will resolve it.

Reference I used to do your setup
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver15&pivots=cs1-bash

NOTE: There is a separate MS Sql server image in docker for Ubuntu. I believe you are using an image for linux.

My sql server which is running in docker inside ubuntu Az VM:
[image]

My Azure ubuntu VM config:
[image]

My NSG inbound port rule:
[image]

Connection from SSMS:

[image]

Connection details:
[image]

Comment: It's not working for me :( Can you show me how you are entering the credentials in SSMS? 
servername: 138.91.187.131,1433  ?

Comment: you have to use sql server authentication to enter the user name and password.I have uploaded a screenshot in my answer section - bottom

Comment: I don't think there is an issue with the way I am logging in. Because I am able to login with public ip in SSMS on my laptop if i run docker using just Dockerfile of sql server. But when i do it with docker-compose.. it doesnt work